# Thread Loop with Sleep() or SetTimer

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, sleep

I have an Win32 app that contains 13 SetTimer() calls... I have a doubt: to optimize application performance, would be better to use CreateThread (with infinite loop and Sleep) instead SetTimer? Which of the two ways to a better way and timing of actions?

Sorry for bad english, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't write a custom timer unless you have a very specific need to do so.  I'd guess performance difference would be negligible for most applications.  Plus you'll run into other issues I'm sure you're not currently considering, like data synchronization, communicating with your GUI thread for user interactions, etc.  It's possible you could even make performance worse.

If you feel you have a specific need, state what that need is and maybe we can guide the answer.